# Interface has no field or method for an exported field in a struct

Tags: go

I have code that has following structure:

```
// $GOPATH/experiments/interfaceexport/printer/printer.go
package printer

import "fmt"

type ResourcePrinter interface {
    PrintSomething()
}

type JSONPrinter struct {
    IsGeneric bool
}

func (printer *JSONPrinter) PrintSomething() {
    fmt.Println("JSON")
}

// $GOPATH/experiments/interfaceexporter/printerretriever/printerretriever.go
package printer

import "experiments/interfaceexporter/printer"

func GetPrinter() printer.ResourcePrinter {
  return &printer.JSONPrinter{IsGeneric: true}
}


// $GOPATH/experiments/interfaceexport/main.go
import "experiments/intefaceexport/printerretriever"

func main() {
  printer := printerretriever.GetPrinter()

  printer.PrintSomething() // "JSON"
  // interfaceexport/main.go:13: printer.IsGeneric undefined (type printer.ResourcePrinter has no field or method IsGeneric)
  if printer.IsGeneric {
    printer.PrintSomething()
  }
}
```

When I do `go run main.go` I get following error:

`interfaceexport/main.go:13: printer.IsGeneric undefined (type printer.ResourcePrinter has no field or method IsGeneric)`

Why do I get above error even though `IsGeneric` is exported?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`printer.ResourcePrinter` is an interface, not the actual instance JSONPrinter, which does have access to IsGeneric

You would need to add a method `IsGeneric()` to your interface (and implement it in `JSONPrinter`) in order to be able to use that interface as you want.

See "[golang how to access interface fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21796240/6309)": you could also extract the dynamic value held by the interface variable through a type assertion:

```
dynamic_value := printer.(JSONPrinter)
```

Then `dynamic_value` would have access to the `IsGeneric` attribute.

See more at "[How to access attribute of interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30356759/6309)".

---

> Even though compiler knows that `printer.ResourcePrinter` is an interface, it says that `IsGeneric` could also be a field.

The dynamic value of the interface can have field (see "[Get all fields from an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39866671/6309)")

The no field part, when applied to [an interface](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types), can refer to an embedded type, the unqualified type’s name acts as the field name.

```
type ReadWriter interface {
    Read(b Buffer) bool
    Write(b Buffer) bool
}

type File interface {
    ReadWriter  // same as adding the methods of ReadWriter
    Locker      // same as adding the methods of Locker
    Close()
}
```

You also see that kind of error message when using a *pointer* to an interface (when the interface itself includes a pointer of sorts: "[Go: What's the meaning of `interface{}`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23148998/6309)" and "[Cast a struct pointer to interface pointer in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27178682/6309)")

See [issue 10700](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10700)

> When using a new, unfamiliar package, programmers occasionally make the error of using a pointer to an interface type instead of the interface type directly.

Comment: I think I have a beef with "has no field" field part in the error message. Even though compiler knows that printer.ResourcePrinter is an interface, it says that IsGeneric could also be a field. AFAIK there is no way in Go one can define fields, like structs, for interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, your interface has no method `IsGeneric`:

```
type ResourcePrinter interface {
    PrintSomething()
}
```